# Translating someone's CSS To Xamarin iOS for a gradient

Tags: css, swift, xamarin, swift3

I'm having some trouble - a designer made this gradient for me in CSS:

```
background: linear-gradient(180deg, #4a6d9a 0%, rgba(65,160,150,0.8) 100%);
```

I tried this code here, but it seems way wrong (the colors are significantly darker). My guess is i'm missing something important (getting the alpha wrong, or maybe not recognizing the 180deg linear-gradient and how that works/what it means.

```
CGColor[] colors = new CGColor[] { new UIColor(red: 65/255, green: 160 / 255, blue: 150 / 255, alpha: 0.8f ).CGColor, new UIColor(red:0.23f, green:0.62f, blue:0.60f, alpha:0.0f).CGColor};
```

Any chance someone could lend a helping hand? Thanks so much!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think your hex code conversion is off.

`new UIColor(red:0.29f, green:0.43f, blue:0.60f, alpha:0.0f)`

http://uicolor.xyz/#/hex-to-ui